# Android: only one row is visible

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have XML:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/IcdSearchMainPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <own_components.SearchOutput
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- HERE ARE ADDED ROWS WITH RESULTS IN JAVA CODE (look into SearchOutput.java) -->

            </own_components.SearchOutput>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have class SearchOutput.java (which extends LinearLayout) with such a method (generally it adds some graphical components to row and then this row to a ScrollView):

```
public void setResultOutput(ResultContainer result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            LinearLayout resultRow = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            resultRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            resultRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            resultRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            if (i % result.getIterationStep() == 0)
            {
                resultRow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
            }
            addView(resultRow);

            ImageView langFlag = new ImageView(resultRow.getContext());
            langFlag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MainClass.getAssetManager().open(Pathes.FLAGS_DIR + result.get(i)[0] + ".gif"));
                langFlag.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                langFlag.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("IMAGE_OPEN_EXC", e.toString());
            }
            resultRow.addView(langFlag);

            TextView number = new TextView(resultRow.getContext());
            number.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            number.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            number.setText(result.get(i)[1]);
            resultRow.addView(number);

            TextView text = new TextView(resultRow.getContext());
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            text.setText(result.get(i)[2]);
            resultRow.addView(text);
        }
    }
```

PROBLEM:
No matter how many elements are in `result` variable there is always one row showned:
[image]
QUESTION:
What i do wrong? In my opinion logically everything is all right.
Another question: is this way efficient? Maybe i should add results in different way? I ask because there can be plenty of them.

Comment: Replace `resultRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` with `resultRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: I'd highly recommend using a ListView for that.

Comment: @Danil: It will cause only flag will be at the top, "A00.0" under the flag, text under "A00.0". It will not make other rows will appear.

Comment: What extends SearchOutput class?

Comment: I forgot to add that SearchOutput extends LinearLayout. It is in fact one object (i hope) who should be wrapped. Anyway, if ScrollView contains more than one element, log returns error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ScrollView can have only one child, so wrap your layouts in another big layout which you add to your ScrollView.

But as suggested in the comments, use a ListView!!! That's what it's for...especially when you have many rows to display. ListView will recycle unused views and definitely yield a better performance than your approach.

Comment: I forgot to add that SearchOutput extends LinearLayout. It is in fact one object (i hope) who should be wrapped. Anyway, if ScrollView contains more than one element, log returns error.

Comment: COMMENT TO SOLUTION: i used this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html to learn how to use ListView. Now everything works properly.

Comment: Wise choice, vogella's tutorials are pretty good, I come back to them once in a while too :)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view is a container that make its own child scrollable, so, you will have to add a child to the scrollview, later add the items to that child.
No master what is the child, it can be list view, can be linear layout, etc.

Comment: I've add it in xml and in code. Do you see anything which wasn't added? Maybe i missed something?

Comment: try to scroll with both direction, if some other row can be seen, try to adjust the scrollview size